# Change substring in a string to an corresponding item in a dictionary using Python

Tags: python

I get a string like "29 jan. 2021". I want to convert the swedish substring "jan." to the corresponding english month name, in this case "Jan" so the result would be "29 Jan 2021". Then I can use this string to convert it into a date object.

I have a dictionary that has a key:value with the swedish key name and corresponding english month name as value:

```
monthNameDictionary = {
    "jan.": "Jan",
    "feb.": "Feb",
    "mars": "Mar",
    "apr.": "Apr",
    "maj": "May",
    "juni": "Jun",
    "juli": "Jul",
    "aug.": "Aug",
    "sep.": "Sep",
    "okt.": "Oct",
    "nov.": "Nov",
    "dec.": "Dec",
}
```

How can I use this or some other way to convert the string into a string with the english month name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness: If you really want to replace the strings, use this (assumes that every string to be replaced is present at most once):

```py
monthDict = {
    "jan.": "Jan",
    "feb.": "Feb",
    "mars": "Mar",
    "apr.": "Apr",
    "maj": "May",
    "juni": "Jun",
    "juli": "Jul",
    "aug.": "Aug",
    "sep.": "Sep",
    "okt.": "Oct",
    "nov.": "Nov",
    "dec.": "Dec",
}
inStr = "29 jan. 2021"
for month in monthDict: # iterating directly over a dict iterates over it's keys
    inStr = inStr.replace(month, monthDict[month])
print(inStr)
```

EDIT: If you have multiple occurrences of the same word, use `inStr = re.sub(month, monthDict, inStr)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This should work,

```
>>> monthNameDictionary = {
    "jan.": "Jan",
    "feb.": "Feb",
    "mars": "Mar",
    "apr.": "Apr",
    "maj": "May",
    "juni": "Jun",
    "juli": "Jul",
    "aug.": "Aug",
    "sep.": "Sep",
    "okt.": "Oct",
    "nov.": "Nov",
    "dec.": "Dec",
}
>>> s = "29 jan. 2021"
>>> op = s.split(" ")
>>> op
['29', 'jan.', '2021']
>>> op[1] = monthNameDictionary[op[1]]
>>> op
['29', 'Jan', '2021']
>>> " ".join(op)
'29 Jan 2021'
>>>
```

**If you prefer oneline solution, here it is**

```
>>> " ".join([monthNameDictionary.get(i, i) for i in s.split(" ")])
'29 Jan 2021'
>>>
```

Comment: Not a generic solution at all.

Comment: OP didn't ask for the generic answer. Simply asking for the specific case. Iterating dictionary is not a big deal, OP can do it if needed.

Comment: @AppCreator, updated answer with oneline solution. Please check it out.

Comment: How is this not "generic"? It solves the stated problem and makes proper use of the O(1) lookup in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `strptime` for this specific format, like so:

```py
import datetime as dt
date_obj = dt.datetime.strptime('29 jan. 2021', '%d %b. %Y')
```

I would generally recommend checking out this page for figuring out how to parse date strings: https://strftime.org/

Finally, if you want to convert it back to another format, you can use `strftime`

```py
print(date_obj.strftime('%d %b %Y'))
```

EDIT: I saw you have norwegian? dates in your question, and need to convert those to english. Plus the format changes for some months

Here is a generic solution to your problem

```py
import datetime as dt
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "nn_NO")
dates = ['29 apr. 2021', '20 mars 2021', '1 okt. 2019', '5 juni 1990']
date_objs = []
for d in dates:
    fmt = '%d %b. %Y' if '.' in d else '%d %B %Y'
    date_objs.append(dt.datetime.strptime(d, fmt))

print(date_objs)
```

Comment: I tried. The problem is that the key is sometimes "apr." , and sometimes "juli" with respective without a dot, hence the format is sometimes '%d %b. %Y' and sometimes '%d %b %Y'.

Comment: @AppCreator Made a generic solution for your norwegian dates that works for all the different date types.. maybe useful for you if you dont want to make a custom dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
monthNameDictionary = {'jan.': 'Jan', 'feb.': 'Feb', 'mars': 'Mar', 'apr.': 'Apr', 'maj': 'May', 'juni': 'Jun', 'juli': 'Jul', 'aug.': 'Aug', 'sep.': 'Sep', 'okt.': 'Oct', 'nov.': 'Nov', 'dec.': 'Dec'}
s = "29 jan. 2021"
new_s = re.sub('(?<=\d\s)[a-z]+\.', lambda x:monthNameDictionary[x.group()], s)
```

Output:

```
'29 Jan 2021'
```